# Rng Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'. >

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am on MacBook Pro 16" intel 2019. I am using android studio and my flutter doctor output is given below:

```
/Users/macbook/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter doctor --verbose [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.1, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 2.5.1 at /Users/macbook/Developer/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision ffb2ecea52 (3 months ago), 2021-09-17 15:26:33 -0400
    • Engine revision b3af521a05
    • Dart version 2.14.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0-rc3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/macbook/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0-rc3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.5, Build version 12E262
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 arm (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 96.0.4664.93

• No issues found!
```

my flutter app was running perfectly before but today when I tried to run the app it was taking unexpectedly long time and after 14 mins it get crashed displaying the following message on console:

```
    Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...  
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.  * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'. > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.    > Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6).      Required by:          project :app       > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk.          > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml.
> Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml'.
> Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway  * Try: Run with
--stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights. 
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org  BUILD FAILED in 14m 56s [!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download... 
    Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
```

and after that error, an error appeared in my android app/build.gradle file.

help me as soon as possible because I have to remove this error till Monday. if you need any more info let me know

Comment: Is your network stable? I see gradle fails downloading some stuffs

Answer (score 0):

Check the `build.gradle` file in `android/` folder (not `android/app`), ensure you have `mavenCentral()` in repositories block.

Then use `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'` or

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:12.2.0'
```

Then rebuild project.

Comment: " mavenCentral() " is already there in my android/build.gradle file. and in app/build.gradle file I have updated the implementation from 'implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)''  to " implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:12.2.0' " but it is still stuck on Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... and after 10 mins it crashed again

Comment: With same stacktrace? Or different?

Comment: Thanks brother.it start working with your help. It was not working earlier maybe android studio was creating some issues but now it's working fine.

Comment: Glad to help! If the answer solved your problem, please be sure to accept it :)